# Robot model parameter not found

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, moveit-commander, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a move_group configuration for my robot but anytime I try to run the `moveit_commander` using `rosrun moveit_commander moveit_commander_cmdline.py`, I get a

> Robot model parameter not found! Did
> you remap 'robot_description'?

error.

When I ran my `rosparam list|grep robot_description_semantic` and `rosparam list|grep robot_description`. I noticed the `robot_description` and `robot_description_semantic` are in the namespace `/robot/robot_description` and `/robot/robot_description_semantic`. How do I run `moveit_commander` in a specific namespace since I'm running multiple robot?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
[ERROR] [1551552307.036199597, 701.961000000]: Robot model parameter not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/bin/moveit_commander_cmdline.py", line 166, in <module>
    run_interactive(opt.group_name)
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/bin/moveit_commander_cmdline.py", line 91, in run_interactive
    c = MoveGroupCommandInterpreter()
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/interpreter.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._robot = RobotCommander()
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/robot.py", line 151, in __init__
    self._r = _moveit_robot_interface.RobotInterface(robot_description, ns)
RuntimeError: RobotInterfacePython: invalid robot model
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317217/robot-model-parameter-not-found/) by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-03-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-02**:
Could you please clarify why you've built MoveIt from source on Kinetic?

**Comment by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on 2019-03-02**:
I can't really remember why, but most likely because the guide I used built from source. But it seems to work fine. Is there any reason why I shouldn't?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:\

> Is there any reason why I shouldn't?

yes, multiple in fact:

- building MoveIt takes quite some time
- source builds are not automatically updated
- you're tracking a development branch (ie: not a stable release)
- potential for vague problems
- difficult to reproduce for others

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:
If you don't need the from-source build, I'd actually strongly recommend to remove it and just do a:

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-moveit
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:
Could you please also tell us which guide/tutorial you followed? Building from source is only needed/desirable in a few select situations. For most users, installing the binaries makes much more sense, so I'd like to make sure the page you refer to explains that.

**Comment by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on 2019-03-03**:
Thanks. I've installed the binary. But I can't remember the guide/tutorial I followed, I'll share it once I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several ways to accomplish this:

1. The `ns` parameter in a `<node>` tag in a launch file sets the namespace that the node runs in: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node (You could also use many other tags that let you specify a `ns` attribute, e.g., the `<group>` tag)
2. You could also use the [ROS_NAMESPACE environment variable](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_NAMESPACE).
3. You could use the [`__ns` "special key" remapping argument](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) with `rosrun`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2019-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on 2019-03-02**:
Your answer answers the question, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem I have. I've updated the question to show the error with the traceback. Thanks.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-03-02**:
Looks like there is something about your `/robot/robot_description` parameter that is causing it to not be parsed correctly. You could edit your question to provide a copy of that parameter (use `rosparam get -p /robot/robot_description > tmp.urdf` and add tmp.urdf)

**Comment by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on 2019-03-02**:
@jarvisschultz I've updated the question to show the robot_description.

**Comment by [caru](https://answers.ros.org/users/44649/caru/) on 2019-09-09**:
Hey,@jarvisschultz! Have you already fixed it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed this by doing

```
rosrun moveit_commander moveit_commander_cmdline.py robot_description:="wx200/robot_description"
```

As you noticed, you can find your robot description by doing

```
rosparam list | grep robot_description
```

Although, after it starts, I can't seem to get the "use" command to work.

---

Originally posted by [Void](https://answers.ros.org/users/28605/void/) with karma: 71 on 2019-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1